# Slim PHP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I'm currently attempting to set up a Slim project with the following directory tree:

```
public_html
|-- Mini
|-- public
|-- vendor
|-- index.php (Slim)
|-- .htaccess
```

The document root is `public_html`, and the contents of the `.htaccess` are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Despite this seemingly simple structure, I am unable to get anything other than a `500 Internal Server Error` when trying to access the domain root or any subdirectories.

This all works on my local WAMP setup.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you enabled error printing to see what it is complaining about?

Comment: Check your error log for more information about 500 Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Issue was tantamount to permissions, and was resolved with the following:

`chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w /path`

Found at https://superuser.com/a/91966/334807

Answer (score 0):

I am hosting at IONOS on a shared server so my possibilites were somewhat restricted. I tried all of the above and from other forums, but to no success.

The only thing that helped me was to add the full URL to index.php in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ http://my.domain.com/index.php [QSA,L]
```

However, if you use $basePath in your code to refer to non-script content like images, that will not work anymore. In my case I defined a constant SITE_URL for that purpose.